# 1997 turbo Diesel Toyota Hilux Gear Selection Problem

Tags: clutch

Got a problem with a turbo Diesel  97 Hilux ute. It now has a recon gear box and new clutch. Problem is sometimes I can put my foot down on the clutch and the car is still in gear and moving (1st, 2nd and reverse), I cannot get it out of gear. I then just turn off the motor then turn it back on and am able to get it out of gear. Any Idea?

Comment: What are you asking? Please ask a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your clutch isn't bled correctly, causing it to not disengage from the engine.

Turning the car on/off (are you coasting when you do this?) possibly causes slack in the transmission which allows the gears to be released.

If true, the same effect can be had much easier by simultaneously pulling the gear lever toward neutral while letting off of the accelerator.

Comment: I agree, just ramp on and off the accelerator while moving the shifter (to take the pressure off the gears).

Comment: Seconded, it definitely sounds like the clutch isn't properly disengaging. Is it difficult to get into first when stationary? and if you sit stationary in first without the brakes on, but with the clutch down, does it start to creep forwards (obviously try this on the flat!)